running command when program crashes
I have a Minecraft server that runs on Ubuntu 24 and mincraft1.21.
Sometimes the Minecraft server file suddenly stops working and jumps back to the terminal.
How can I write a Bash program that when this happens the program starts running again?

You could run the server command in a loop.

Also explain what exactly jumps back to the terminal  is supposed to mean.

Write a small wrapper script that runs your server – something like
#!/bin/bash
while true 
do 
    ./minecraft-server-however-you-launch-it
    sleep 1
done

and then run that script instead of minecraft-server-however-you-launch-it.
Better yet, run your server as e.g. a Systemd unit, so Systemd will take care of restarting it if it crashes, and you can use systemctl start etc. to manage it.

is it ok to put this piece of code in the ./profile file?

No, because then it would run every time you attempt to use your shell.
